# Cocoa NSTextField change placeholder color

Tags: cocoa, swift

I try to change the placeholder text color. This code doesn't work:

```
let color = NSColor.redColor()
let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color]
let placeHolderStr = NSAttributedString(string: "My placeholder", attributes: attrs)
myTextField.placeholderAttributedString = placeHolderStr
```

I get the error `-[NSTextField setPlaceholderAttributedString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Any ideas, how I can change the color of the placeholder?

UPDATE:
This works:

```
(myTextField.cell() as NSTextFieldCell).placeholderAttributedString = placeHolderStr
```

UPDATE 2:
Hmm, it changes the color, but if the text field gets the focus, the placeholder font size get's smaller, very strange.

Comment: Though it's not ideal, you can always add an additional attribute for setting the font (NSFontAttributeName), which will prevent the placeholder text from showing smaller than desired.

Comment: Hi, Lupurus, have you found a solution for the smaller font size when the placeholder gets focus? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Seeing the same and wondering how to fix it, although the placeholder goes away when you don't play with the settings @Daniel

Answer (score 11):

By explicitly defining the font of the NSAttributedString, the placeholder font resizing referred to in the original question is fixed.

The following is a working example in Swift 3.0.

```
let color = NSColor.red
let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: font]
let placeholderString = NSAttributedString(string: "My placeholder", attributes: attrs)
(textField.cell as? NSTextFieldCell)?.placeholderAttributedString = placeholderString
```

The following is a working example in Swift 4.2.

```
let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.lightGray,
             NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
let placeholderString = NSAttributedString(string: "My placeholder", attributes: attrs)
(taskTextField.cell as? NSTextFieldCell)?.placeholderAttributedString = placeholderString
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the placeholder text in `NSTextFieldCell` and not `NSTextField`.

```
myTextField.cell.placeholderAttributedString = placeHolderStr
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is no `cell` property at the NSTextField

Comment: @Lupurus There is: `NSTextField().cell // NSCell`

Answer (score 0):

You should keep current font, and current value from IB

```
  extension NSTextField {

    func setHintTextColor (color: NSColor) {
        let currentHint = placeholderString ?? ""
        let placeholderAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: font!
        ]

        let placeholderAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: currentHint, attributes: placeholderAttributes)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

        placeholderAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: placeholderAttributedString.length))

        self.placeholderAttributedString =  placeholderAttributedString
    }
}
```